# Экспорт Word в html с сохранением форматирования

Tags: java, html, docx

Есть ли способ/инструмент, позволяющий экспортировать doc(x) файлы в html с полным сохранением форматирования?

Есть ряд сложных документов - с таблицами, подсказками, сквозной нумерацией, фоновым цветом и т.д.

Из них, в соответствии с выбранными пользователем опциями на форме, я формирую один документ

Идея такая: базовые документы я перегоняю в html, с которым просто работать в Velocity/Freemarker, формирую один html и отдаю пользователю как doc файл.

Но есть одна загвоздка - не получается сохранить форматирование базовых документов. Пробовал экспортировать через MS Office, LibreOffice, ряд доступных конвертеров, через транзит в PDF, но результат очень далек от ожидаемого, и не гарантирует корректного отображения в разных редакторах.

Word отдает монструозный файл (~10k строк на один 8 страничный документ), остальные куда скромнее, но либо вовсе теряют форматирование, либо уродуют его. Меньше всего хотелось бы руками шлифовать каждый файл, т.к. эти в шаблоны документов будут периодически меняться конечными пользователями

Возможно я упустил какой-то очевидный способ разрешения такой проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, нет гарантированного способа конвертации doc(x) файлов в html без потери форматирования.

Выходом из ситуации является использования библиотеки [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), которая предназначена для работы с файлами "офисных" форматов.

Для работы с doc подойдет HWPF, для docx - XWPF.

По ходу использования возникают неочевидные сложности.

Например:

- базовым элементов XWPFDocument является XWPFRun, который псевдослучайным образом (скорее всего в соответствии с версткой в xml) "нарезает" документ, и если вы планировали использовать его для замены ключевых слов, например ${needed_key}, в одном случае он может его считать как один XWPFRun с текстом "${needed_key}", а в другом - как четыре XWPFRun ("${", "needed_", "key", "}"), что придется учитывать при работе с библиотекой.
- Есть сложности при работе с примечаниями (comments), которые в структуре docx-файла пишутся в отдельный comments.xml. XWPFDocument дает доступ к комментариям только на чтение, и для записи комментариев придется использовать разного рода колдунства, например [такие](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491860/how-to-add-comment-by-apache-poi)

Возможно есть еще какие-то подводные камни. Более удобных альтернатив не нашел.

Для (до)записи/чтения - очень удобен. В случаях когда надо что-то вставить в середину документа/и других более сложных манипуляций - возрастает сложность использования.