# Соответствие документа doc/docx некоторому шаблону

Tags: python, ms-word, office

Есть много документов (представим, что это научные работы студентов).
Все документы написаны в MS Office Word и их форматирование должно соответствовать некоторому стандарту (Например какой-нибудь ГОСТ 7.32 2001).

Стандарт регламентирует:

- размер отступов
- стиль шрифта
- размер шрифта
- размер заголовков
- и т.д.

**Существует ли какой-то инструмент (и вдруг он есть на python) с помощью которого можно будет автоматизировать проверку документа на соответствие конечных требований оформления?**

Пробовал использовать библиотеку python-docx. Но ее предназначение это создание документов, а не работа с уже готовыми. С ее помощью нельзя получить стиль шрифтов и размера шрифтов в уже существующем документе. (Вывод сделал опираясь на этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878485/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-word-%D0%B2-html-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В силу внутренней структуры и формата в котором Word работает с файлами нет возможности отслеживать/редактировать/править документы.

Comment: Почему нету? Берете ворд-application activeX и анализируете документ.  Думаю что питон COM и ActiveX понимает. Легких путей - да их нету.